# unable to drag my imageview in different activity android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

```
public class Drag extends SingleItemView implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ViewGroup mRrootLayout;
    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);
        mRrootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(350,350);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        mImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        mRrootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

The above is code to drag an image view.I want to achieve the same thing in different activity.In different activity I am setting the same image view id.
Also in otherjava.class file I am setting the content view for the new activity with these features

Comment: I am dragging my image-view easily in drag.xml,I want to drag the same image view in different activities say drag2.xml. drag2.xml has some more views in it and few functionality in its java class file           (drag2.java )such as camera ,zoom in and zoom out.And in this java class I have set the content vies as drag2.xml. I don"t know how to use the drag feature in this drag2.xml.whose java class file is drag2.java

Answer (score 0):

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
/////////Changed////////
                lastX = X;
                lastY = Y;
/////////Changed////////
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
/////////Changed///////////
xDelta = X - lastX;
yDelta = Y - lastY;
/////////Changed///////////
                layoutParams.leftMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin+xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = layoutParams.topMargin + yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
```

Comment: My problem was not with the code above it working fine...I just need to call the drag.java class or all its methods in drag2.java without extending it.